# Error in trying to strcat a single char to a char* array

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, char, constants

Hello and Happy New Year!

I have a problem on recursion I am trying to solve which looks like the below. I've managed to get it to work, however an alternative method I wanted to use isn't working (the working line commented out).

I am not able to append a single `char` to `char*` array - compiler gives the error `'Unable to convert const char to char'`

I've tried declaring `x1` as array of like `char[1]` instead. I cannot declare x1,x2 as `char*` because they feed into the `bigram` function which takes char by reference specifically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
void encode(char square[6][6], char* prepared, char* encoded){
    // EXIT CONDITION:
    if (strlen(prepared) == 0) {encoded[0] ='\0'; return;}

        encode(square,++++prepared,++++encoded);
        char x1
        char x2; 
        bigram(square, prepared[0],prepared[1],x1,x2);
 
        // bigram(square, prepared[0],prepared[1],encoded[0],encoded[1]); << WORKS
        strcat(prepared,x1); // << DOES NOT WORK with 'cannot convert const char* to char*' error
        strcat(prepared,x2); // << does not work
}

// I have to pass the chars by reference here per problem statement
bool bigram(char square[6][6], char inchar1,char inchar2,char& outchar1,char& outchar2){
    /* some calcs which compute outchar1, outchar2 */
}
```

Comment: Please read the [strcat manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html). The function takes two **strings**. And that's exactly what the  compiler tells you too.

Comment: Assuming enough space in `prepared` ... try `char *preparedend = prepared + strlen(prepared); *preparedend++ = x1; *preparedend = 0;`

Comment: @pmg Thank you!! I got it to work with  `*encoded++ = x1; *encoded++ = x2;`

Comment: @kaylum thank you and fair point. But i've not been able to find any documentation on specfically appending a single character (I typically use std::string where this is not an issue) hence the question - so I figured I'd give strcat a go

Answer (score 1):

To append a single character to a *string*, various approaches exist.  String memory management also needs consideration and usually hints to the best approached.

```
char* append(size_t sz, char *s, char ch) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  if (len + 1 >= sz) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient room\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  // Append via `len`
  s[len++] = ch;
  s[len] = '\0';

  // OR 
  // strcat with compound literal
  strcat(s, (char[2]) {ch});

  return s;
}
```

---

As OP's wants to append 2 characters:

```
char* append2(size_t sz, char *s, char ch1, char ch2) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  if (len + 2 >= sz) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient room\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  // Append via `len`
  s[len++] = ch1;
  s[len++] = ch2;
  s[len] = '\0';

  // OR 
  // strcat with compound literal
  strcat(s, (char[3]) {ch1, ch2});

  return s;
}
```

Pedantic:  Appending a *null character* is a special case not detailed above.

Comment: Thank you!! This is extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (Thank you @pmg !!)

It was as simple as this instead of the two strcats. Strcats DO NOT work on a single character - they have to take a char* on the RHS:

```
*encoded++ = x1; 
*encoded++ = x2;
```

Comment: Don't forget to terminate the string with a `'\0'`... add `*encoded = 0; /* or '\0' */` after your 2 lines.